# Ajax replace instead of append

Tags: jquery, ajax, replace, append

I used the following jQuery [example](http://www.360innovate.co.uk/blog/2009/03/periodicalupdater-for-jquery/)  which works like a charm.  However it appends the results.  What do I need to change to replace the results instead of appending?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

you could empty the element before you append

```
$("#results").empty().append(myHtml);
```

or use the `html` method

```
$("#results").html(myHtml)
```

Comment: It should be noted that `append` supports elements and an array of elements, whereas `html` does not.

Answer (score 27):

Just change

```
$('#results').append(myHtml);
```

to

```
$('#results').html(myHtml);
```

Answer (score 5):

OK, last entry 2009, but if the problem still exist:

```
let oldElement = $('#results')
let content = '<div id="#results>9000+</div>'
oldElement = oldElement.replaceWith(content)
let newElement = $('#results')
```

Comment: Usefull but it does not do the same thing tho, it replace the element instead of inserting content.

Comment: yes, the better way to replace it's content is to use the html method

Comment: The question does not say which type of replacement is needed. `.text()` and `.html()` are for getting and setting the inner content of an element. `.replaceWith()` replaces the element itself. `.empty().append()` together is a convoluted way of doing `.html()`, but might be useful if there is some separation of the statements. Like if new content always gets appended, but only sometimes empties the element first. `.appendTo()` and `.replaceAll()` reverse content and elements (e.g. `$('<div/>').appendTo('body')`). I think `replaceWith()` pairs well with server communications of sections by ID.

Answer (score 0):

Empty function before your append or prepend function.

I tried this & it worked --->

frame is id selector & it append image.

```
$("#frame").empty().append('<img src="" >' );
```