# Append and then change every time

Tags: jquery, append

I am using an `.append` every time I click a button.

```
 $( ".kop_filters" ).append( "<p class='gekozen_datum'>Gekozen datum: </p>" );
```

If I click the button 4 times this is appending in my page like:

```
Gekozen datum:
Gekozen datum:
Gekozen datum:
Gekozen datum:
```

I want it to appear once and every time I click it removes and append again so for example after a couple of times clicking on it I have printed it once. It is because I want to load a variable in it which change every time on click.

EDIT:
Found the solution here: [Ajax replace instead of append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675215/ajax-replace-instead-of-append)

Comment: Found solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675215/ajax-replace-instead-of-append

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ajax replace instead of append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675215/ajax-replace-instead-of-append)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `html` method.

```js
$('button').click(() => {
  $(".kop_filters").html((Math.random() * 10).toString())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kop_filters"></div>
<button>Update</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hii @JacobHout you can use jQuery empty() function like this

```
  $( ".kop_filters" ).empty();
```

this will definitely help you :)